# Change The Woocommerce Product Categories Dropdown Widget Placeholder Text

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, widgets, dropdown, widget-text

I've searched everywhere on the internet and tried to code it myself I want to change the default "Select A Category" placeholder text to "Select A Sub Category" so far I have tried this but it's not working:

function _category_dropdown_filter( $list_args ) {
    $list_args['show_option_none'] = __('Select A Sub Category');
    return $list_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_arg' , '_category_dropdown_filter' );

Also, I have even tried to edit this file here but I see no "Select A Category" woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-product-categories.php

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', function( $html, $args ) {
    if ( $args['taxonomy'] === 'product_cat' ) {
        $html = str_replace( '<select', '<select data-placeholder="New Placeholder"', $html );
    }
    return $html;
}, 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to using `apply_filters` in your functions.php

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args','art_architecture_textbooks' );
function art_architecture_textbooks( $cat_args ) {
        $cat_args['show_option_none'] = __('Art & Architecture');
        return $cat_args;
}
```

Learn more **https://siteorigin.com/thread/change-category-widget-default-text-select-a-category/**

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work I tried that code from siteorigin already and even tried to play around with it and still no luck... :(

Comment: Please also refer **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079259/change-default-select-category-text-in-categories-dropdown-widget-in-wordpress**

Comment: I have done that as well it only changes the Wordpress dropdown categories widget placeholder not the Woocommerce dropdown product categories widget placeholder